# Get data from hidden index on click delete icon in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid-php, mvcjqgrid

[image]

Problem in get data from current row when click on delete button.
I want to get data from hidden field passed from codeigniter controller and get that hidden field data when click on delete button.

```
 {name:'PL_DELETE', index:'PL_DELETE', hidden:true}


 function beforeDeleteCallback(e)
 {    
     // i want to use PL_DELETE field value here on click delete icon.
 }
```

PL_DELETE column contain active / inactive value only.

if value is inactive than we can delete this row otherwise return false.

Thank U in Advance...... :)

Comment: It's unclear what kind of "delete button" you use. It's depend on what you need to do with the information from `beforeDeleteCallback`. There are exist `beforeSubmit` and `onclickSubmit` which can be used for the goal. `onclickSubmit` is practical to extend the data, sent to the server. `beforeSubmit` can be used to *preventing* deleting of the row. Moreover it's unclear which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).